# What does this mean? "osascript: Please update this scripting addition to supply a value for ThreadSafe"

Tags: macos, mac, osascript

Every 10 seconds, I get this message a few times in Console:

`27.08.11 16:40:21,034 osascript: Performance: Please update this scripting addition to supply a value for ThreadSafe for each event handler: "/Library/ScriptingAdditions/SIMBL.osax"`

I wonder what it means and what I am supposed to do.

---

Also, what can I do (except of uninstalling SIMBL) to make SIMBL stop spamming the system logs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You installed [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php), a tool for patching applications at runtime. Mac OS X isn't happy that SIMBL doesn't declare whether its event handlers are [thread-safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

---

You can find an explanation for this issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/simbl/issues/detail?id=7):

> This is a dopey cosmetic issue -- the warning is 100% spurious.
>
> The event handler used in Snow Leopard is correctly labeled as thread-unsafe.  The problem is that this warning
> is about the event used for Leopard - which is completely unaware of thread issues. I can't figure out how to get
> it to be backward compatible and stop complaining, so I'll let it complain.

---

Based on my understanding of the source code, you can try editing the `Info.plist` in the SIMBL bundle and remove the following from it:

```
<key>SIMeleop</key>
<string>InjectEventHandler</string>
```

It's the Leopard-specific event handler (`leop`).

Comment: Ah, thanks for the link! But (and I forgot to mention that) I also want to get rid of these messages. :)

Comment: Uninstall SIMBL like the rest of us did. Otherwise, live with the pain, because you can't turn off those messages.

Comment: I need SIMBL so that is not an option. SIMBL is open source, so there must be a way.

Comment: I also forked it on GitHub and [here](https://github.com/albertz/simbl/commit/93772b8cf1bcadcf58f9fa3679d735a938394fb7) is a patch.

Comment: Where is the `Info.plist` file found? Also I'm confused from your comments as to wether or not editing the plist file will stop the errors from showing up in the console...

Comment: @cwd It's within the SIMBL bundle, specified in the error message. Remove the Leopard specific event handler if you have a more recent version of OS X and the error should disappear, perhaps after a system restart.

Comment: perfect! thanks! and yes - this was on Lion and so I removed that entry and it started working - no restart needed! Can't believe I didn't think to look in the console.app line to see where that plist file was :/

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the info.

I went to the developer's website and updated SIMBL to the latest, and all is good now http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php

The latest SIMBL installer also contains an "uninstall SIMBL" app, should the need arise.